# Creating two lines with package dplyr

Tags: r

I have data in CSV format (NDVI, LST) I was able to make the  Scatter plot  but for the two linear regression  is not really obvious to do it : knowing that the first straight line passing through the maximum of the point clouds and the other line by the minimum of the point clouds

```
LSTmax = a + b NDVI
LSTmin = a '+ b' NDVI
```

someone advise me to use the package (dplyr) below you will find the script idea

```
library(dplyr)
# df is a dataframe with NDVI and Ts information
dry_edge<- df %>% group_by(ndvi) %>% top_n(1, ts) # here is the code to get the top 1%
wet_edge <- df %>% group_by(ndvi) %>% top_n(-1, ts) # here is the code to get the botton 1%
```

---

yes you have all the right at the same time i should to read more about all the basics of the R that's what i'm currently to doing but in my project i have the problem with some of data cause in each of them didn't find a correlation, this one I can find a good relation between LST and NDVI. Below is the point clouds picture.

[image]

---

In your opinion is it confused with that of this model in order to determine the coefficients?

[image]

Comment: I should to select to select the top 1% of Ts for the occurrence of NDVI in your area (Dry edge) and after the lowest 1% of Ts for the occurrence of NDVI (wet edge). For this I used the

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information.

Comment: Let's see if I understand this. You have a data frame with two columns, one is NDVI and the other is LST. You want to take the rows with the 1% highest LST values and fit a linear model. Then do the same with the rows with the 1% lowest LST values, giving you two linear model fits. Is that correct and clear?

Comment: yeahh that's it what i'm currently resarching

Comment: I've answered your question and it looks like you have got it to work on your data. Great! You should "tick" my answer to show it works for you. If you now have *further* questions about the correctness of these lines to your method, then create *a new* question for that. Include your graph with the lines and the code you used to create it, and then your question.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a data frame with two columns. You should show part of that so we know what you have. I've created a random one:

```
df <- data.frame(
    ndvi = runif(4321,0,1),
    ts = runif(4321, 23, 57)
)

head(df)

        ndvi       ts
1 0.66967785 36.47674
2 0.89686408 27.06128
3 0.11688687 37.42891
4 0.07607912 43.13066
5 0.16757402 35.98790
6 0.72767844 46.93965
```

To find a cutoff value that separates a vector into two parts given a fraction, use `quantile`. You don't need to install or learn any other packages.

```
> cutoffs = quantile(df$ts, c(0.01, 0.99))
> cutoffs
      1%      99% 
23.35454 56.70370
```

Those values are the cutoffs - so 1% of the `ts` values are below 23.35454, and 1% are above 56.70370.

Create two `TRUE/FALSE` vectors based on those cutoffs:

```
lower = df$ts < cutoffs[1]
upper = df$ts > cutoffs[2]
```

and check to see if we have 1% of TRUE in each:

```
> sum(lower)
[1] 44
> sum(upper)
[1] 44
```

OK, 44 out of 4321 is 1% near enough.

Now we can use those logical vectors to subset our data. Let's plot all the data and then add the upper points in red and the lower ones in blue:

```
plot(df$ndvi, df$ts, pch=19, cex=0.5)
points(df$ndvi[upper], df$ts[upper], pch=19, col="red")
points(df$ndvi[lower], df$ts[lower], pch=19, col="blue")
```

[image]

Now let's fit linear models on those subsets, add the lines, and print the model coefficients:

```
upperline = lm(ts~ndvi, data=df[upper,])
lowerline = lm(ts~ndvi, data=df[lower,])

abline(upperline, col="red")
abline(lowerline, col="blue")
```

[image]

Looks like its fitted each set of coloured points by the coloured lines. Coefficients:

```
> summary(upperline)$coeff
               Estimate Std. Error      t value      Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 56.86365004 0.02544160 2235.0659047 3.204031e-108
ndvi         0.01458156 0.04423496    0.3296389  7.433112e-01
> summary(lowerline)$coeff
               Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 23.18750457 0.03124581 742.099656 4.129260e-88
ndvi        -0.01571813 0.05301834  -0.296466 7.683354e-01
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping by the way my data is in CSV , i think also i can doing the same thing

Comment: You said you had made a scatterplot so I assumed you knew how to read your data from the CSV into a data frame.

Comment: already done the Scatter plot yeah , i just asking cause at the same time cause i'm a beginner thanks a lot for your helping.

Comment: So does my answer answer your question?

Comment: But the problem when i applicate on my data it seems like exactly , i mean the same of  your result !!. how i can add here my data (in format of CSV) also the scatter plot of my data !!

Comment: The first thing I do above is to make a data frame called `df` with random numbers. What you do is to read your data in from CSV using `read.csv` or `read.table` or something to create a data frame *like* the `df` I created with the named columns. If you can't do **that** then you need to read up on basic data input in R and then ask a question on Stack Overflow if you get stuck. You are trying to run before you can walk.